# Help needed for SSD Installation on an Mid-2012 MacBook Pro with BootCamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, ssd

I have a 13-inch Mid-2012 MacBook Pro, and I want to switch over from the HDD (1 TB) to SSD (1 TB). I am concerned about the following things:

1. I have BootCamp installed, so when I install the SSD, will I be able to get all the files from both BootCamp and MacOS as they are right now?
2. I have installed a Patched version of Big Sur on my MacBook Pro, and I have had to enter the following commands (only if I reset the NVRAM) or else it will not allow me to boot up (the crossed out circle sign):

> 1. nvram boot-args="-no_compat_check"
> 2. nvram csr-active-config=%7f%08%00%00

Will this create further problems? Or would I be able to boot up without any issues?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main points:

1. You need to transfer everything from the old disk onto the new disk.
2. You need to be running an OS while you're doing it!

So, you need to have both the old and the new drive connected to the computer at the same time. This usually involves an SATA-to-USB cable or external disk enclosure box, which are quite cheap.

I've used either [SuperDuper!](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) to clone the entire disk in the past; you'll have to check whether they can deal with BootCamp partitions.

Otherwise, you'll have to setup BootCamp anew on the new disk, and then transfer the Windows partition from the old disk separately.

It goes without saying that you should make sure you have a backup of everything before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should get away with `dd if=/dev/hdx of=/dev/hdy` ([dd](https://pbxbook.com/other/dd_clone.html)) executed in macOS Recovery's Terminal, where `if` is source and `of` is destination. *Don't accidentally swap IF with OF or you will erase contents of your source drive.* This will copy device-to-device by 512-byte blocks keeping your partition map (including EFI contents required to boot Windows). Here's a short quote of a [good write-up](https://pbxbook.com/other/dd_clone.html) on how it works with screenshots and example that fits your need perfectly:

> dd (disk duplication) is a Mac OS X command-line utility which can
> read raw data off a disk, even if the Mac doesn't understand the
> filesystem. There's also a freeware version of dd for Windows
> available, with instructions.

P.S. Windows might not boot after disk has changed (cloned to). This should be possible to fix this way. Boot to source Windows drive, attach destination drive with cloned partitions, mount EFI volume of destination drive to letter `V:` (Command Prompt > `diskpart` > `list disk` > `select disk 2` *(2 is your destination drive, double-check this)* > `list partition` > `select partition 1` *(1 is EFI partition on destination drive, should be 200 MB)* > `assign letter v:` > `exit` **or** Win+R > `diskmgmt.msc` > right-click EFI on external drive > Assign letter), execute Command Prompt command `BCDBOOT Z:\Windows /S V: /F ALL` ([bcdboot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di?view=windows-11), perhaps you could use `BIOS` or `UEFI` instead of `ALL` but I don't know type of your installation) where `Z:` is your external drive's Windows partition. Please note that you should track disk number, partition and letters by your own, it's just an example. After that Windows partition on newly cloned disk should become bootable again. Once again, it maybe good to go without this extra step of re-writing boot sector.

P.P.S. If you're not sure what you're doing you may also try using Clonezilla, here's [a video example](https://youtu.be/n_XuBhVVTCM).